# What are "referred" speeds and "referred TET"?

Tags: jet-engine

i'm currently reading the Rolls Royce publication *[The Jet Engine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119065992)*. It makes reference to "referred speed", "referred TET" and "referred mass flow". Referred speed seems to be defined as N/sqrt(T). I guess that N is engine speed but I'm not clear on why it is divided by the root of temperature. Also can someone advise how referred mass flow and referred TET are defined please?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I added a link to the book you mentioned, if it's wrong then you can just edit again to correct it.

Comment: Yes that is the correct book.

Answer (score 1):

Referred speed is a way of compensating for the fact that air density changes with temperature.  For example, let's say you are designing a new turbojet engine. You fire up your engine one warm sunny day in July, and note that when the shaft speed is 5,000 rpm, it's making 10,000 pounds of thrust.  But then later, on a cold winter evening in December, you run the engine to 5,000 rpm, and now it's making 11,000 pounds of thrust!  What happened?  Did your engine suddenly get more efficient?  No.  It's just that colder air is more dense.  So for that same 5,000 rpm, you are pumping a lot more mass of air. Now, where referred speed comes in.  You are going to have to tell the pilot of the plane how to set thrust.  i.e. he wants to get 10,000 pounds of thrust, no more and no less.  You can't just tell him to set 5,000 rpm, because that will be a different amount of thrust depending on the ambient temperature.  So you tell him to set a specific "referred speed".  If you go to the same referred speed, you'll always get the same amount of thrust, no matter what the temperature.

You should also look up corrected speeds.  That is a very similar concept.

Comment: Good simple answer. I would suggest corrected and referred speeds are basically exactly the same thing, except maybe the correction factor in the formula for referred speeds is specific to a certain engine type, where was the corrected speed formula is assumed to be the same for any gas turbine.